# Where is my mistake when I am trying to solve $| \int_{\Gamma} \frac{1} {(z^2 +1)^2} dz | $

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find an upper bound for
> $$ \bigg| \int_{\Gamma} \frac{1} {(z^2 +1)^2} dz \bigg|.$$

where Γ is the upper half-circle |z| = a with radius a > 1 traversed once in the counter clockwise direction.

I know the correct answer but I didn't know where I get wrong.

The following is my solution

$$
\bigg|\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1} {(a^2 e^{2i \theta} +1)^2} d (a e^{i \theta}) \bigg |
$$

$$
\bigg |\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1} {(a^2 e^{2i \theta} +1)^2} (a i e^{i \theta}) d \theta \bigg |
$$

$$
\bigg |\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{(a i e^{i \theta})} {(a^2 e^{2i \theta} +1)^2}  d \theta \bigg |
$$

$$
\bigg |\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{(a i e^{i \theta})} {(a^2 e^{2i \theta} +1)^2}  d \theta \bigg |
$$

$$
\bigg |\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{(a i e^{i \theta})} {(a^2 e^{2i \theta} +1)^2}  d \theta \bigg |
\leq
\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\bigg |(a i e^{i \theta}) \bigg |} {|(a^2 e^{2i \theta} +1)^2|}  d \theta
$$

$$
\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{|(a i (\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)|} {|(a^2 e^{2i \theta} +1)^2|}  d \theta
$$

$$
\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{|(a i \cos \theta - a \sin \theta)|} {|(a^2 e^{2i \theta} +1)^2|}  d \theta
$$

$$
\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{a} {|(a^2 e^{2i \theta} +1)^2|}  d \theta
$$

$$
\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{a} {|(a^4 e^{4i \theta} + 2 a^2 e^{2i \theta} + 1)^2|}  d \theta
$$

$$
\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{a} {|(a^4 \cos 4\theta + 2 a^2 \cos 2\theta + 1) + 
(a^4 \sin 4\theta + 2 a^2 \sin 2\theta) i|}  d \theta
$$

$$
\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{a} {\sqrt{(a^4 \cos 4\theta + 2 a^2 \cos 2\theta + 1)^2 + 
(a^4 \sin 4\theta + 2 a^2 \sin 2\theta)^2}}  d \theta
$$

$$
\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{a} {\sqrt{
{\left(1+2\ \cos\left(2\ \theta \right)\ a^2+a^4\right)}^2
}} d \theta
$$

Because a > 1 and $\theta \in [0, \pi]$, $\Rightarrow 1+2\ \cos\left(2\ \theta \right)\ a^2+a^4 \geq 0$

$$
\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{a} {
{\left(1+2\ \cos\left(2\ \theta \right)\ a^2+a^4\right)}
} d \theta
$$

Use matlab symbolic function.

$$
\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{a} {
{\left(1+2\ \cos\left(2\ \theta \right)\ a^2+a^4\right)}
} d \theta =
\frac{a \pi} {a^4 -1}
$$

$$
\bigg| \int_{\Gamma} \frac{1} {(z^2 +1)^2} dz \bigg | \leq
\frac{a \pi} {a^4 -1}
$$

$$
 \int_{\Gamma} \frac{1} {(z^2 +1)^2} dz  =
\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1} {(a^2 e^{2i \theta} +1)^2} (a i e^{i \theta}) d \theta =
-\frac{a} {a^2 + 1} + \frac{\pi}{2} + tan^{-1} a
,
(a>1)
$$

Comment: @insipidintegrator Thank you for making abs bigger

Comment: Without knowing which expression you meant to be less than or equal to, or equal to, it's hard to say where you went wrong. May you edit your post that way?

Comment: @Accelerator I have already edited. Please look at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I meant the whole chain of integrals, not just the bottom of the page. I only see one inequality symbol before "Because $a>1$".

Comment: ... what makes you think your answer is wrong? The task: "find an upper bound" has infinitely many solutions

Comment: @Accelerator The fifth equation (From top to bottom) is also the inequality symbol I am talking about.

Comment: @FShrike Because the answer is different from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a classic bound, best seen by geometric reasoning: $$\left|\int_\Gamma\frac{1}{(z^2+1)^2}\,\mathrm{d}z\right|<\frac{\pi a}{(a^2-1)^2}$$

Which is slightly sharper than yours, $a>1$. The explanation: $\Gamma$ traces a half-circle - the locus of $z^2,\,z\in\Gamma$ traces a *full* circle (circle wraps around, arguments double...) of radius $a^2$. When you add $1$, you shift this to a circle of radius $a^2$ with centre $1$ - the minimum modulus (distance to the origin!) of any complex number on the circumference is 'clearly' given by that point of this locus on the real axis closest to the origin, which is the point $1-a^2$. The minimum modulus of $z^2+1$ is $a^2-1$, $a>1$, among $z\in\Gamma$.

That means I can bound the integrand from above by: $$\frac{1}{(a^2-1)^2}$$And the inequality follows.

[image]

Comment: I think $(z-1)^2$ is correct expression for your big red circle. I don't know why you said $z^2 +1$ is

Comment: @kile I said $a^2-1$ is, and that's because the new circle has radius $a^2$.

Comment: How can it be $a^2-1$? The red circle should be $(z-1)^2 = 4^2$ in the complex domain

Comment: That is true. And what is $-3$? It is $1-(2^2)$!

Comment: What do you mean -3? Where do you find it?

Comment: @kile It's my example "minimum distance" point

Comment: The question is $\frac{1}{(z^2+1)^2}$. Can you explain why do you use $(z-1)^2 = 4^2$?

Comment: @kile It was just a graphical example with $a=2$.

Comment: I still don't understand why you  have this red circle $(z-1)^2 = 4^2$? I believe it has nothing to do with $(z^2+1)^2$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140548/discussion-between-fshrike-and-kile).